# Quais as diferenças entre os métodos "equals()", "compareTo()", e até mesmo "=="?

Tags: java, operadores, método, comparação

Estou ciente que existe diferenças entre se comparar objetos utilizando `equals()`, `compareTo()` e até mesmo o operador `==`, mas detalhadamente quais são as diferenças entre elas e os cuidados que devemos tomar na utilização de cada uma?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma diferença óbvia entre `equals()`, `compareTo()` é que eles retornam coisas diferentes, o primeiro retorna um booleano e já pode, por exemplo, ser usado em um `if`, enquanto que o segundo retorna um numérico de acordo com a igualdade (0) ou se é menor (um número negativo de acordo com o critério daquele objeto) ou maior (um número positivo de acordo com o critério daquele objeto), portanto ele dá uma informação mais precisa, não é só sobre ser igual ou não, então para usar em um `if` tem que comparar com um desses números para gerar um booleano.

Além disso o primeiro está disponível em todos os objetos porque ele está em [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html), já o segundo só está presente em tipos que implementem a interface [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Ainda o `equals()` retorna um booleano mesmo que o argumento seja nulo. O `compareTo()` lança uma exceção nessa situação, ele exige que os objetos sejam válidos. Ambos lançam exceção se o objeto principal usado for nulo.

A implementação de como verificar a igualdade ou comparar o seu conteúdo é livre e cada objeto faz como achar melhor. O `equals()` sempre terá uma implementação se o objeto não prover, mas em geral isso não é uma boia ideia.

O operador `==` sempre analisa o valor das variáveis ou literais usados, então tipos primitivos analisam a igualdade do valor do objeto (já que o valor já é o objeto) e tipos por referência (`class`) analisam a igualdade da referência, por isso só dá igual se for o mesmo objeto. Esse é o motivo que as pessoas quebram a cara quando tentam comparar `String` com o operador, mesmo que o conteúdo seja igual, se for outro objeto é diferente.

Não sei o que vai acontecer agora que Java terá tipos por valor que não são primitivos, em tese o operador deveria comparar o valor do objeto, mas não tem sobrecarga de operador, então ou vão abandonar isso ou criarão alguma regra para ele assumir o mesmo que o `equals()`, ou algo assim, não estou acompanhando a evolução dessa nova *feature*, que será revolucionária para o Java. Acho que está demorando para sair justamente porque tem uma incompatibilidade que precisa lidar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).