# Como aplicar uma condição se todos valores de uma lista forem iguais Java

Tags: java

Tenho uma lista de Pessoas e quero saber saber como fazer pra saber se todos esses objetos são iguais, Independente de qualquer matricula, usuarioPadrao, regra de negócio, etc...

esse trecho é do Controller

```
@Transacional
@Post("app/mesa2/")
public void gravarUsuarioPadraoSelecionado() {

    String cpfFormatado = request.getParameter("cpfFormatado");
    Long cpf = Long.valueOf(cpfFormatado.replaceAll("\\D", ""));

    Long id = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
    CpDao.getInstance().consultaEGravaUsuarioPadrao(id, cpf);
    
    result.redirectTo("/app/mesa2");
}
```

esse trecho é do dao

```
public DpPessoa consultaEGravaUsuarioPadrao(long id, long cpf){

    final Query qry = em().createNamedQuery("consultarPessoaAtualPelaInicial");
    qry.setParameter("idPessoaIni", id);
    final DpPessoa pes = (DpPessoa) qry.getResultStream().findFirst().orElse(null);
    
    List<DpPessoa> lista  = obterUsuarioPadrao(cpf);
    
    for(DpPessoa pessoa : lista) {
            pessoa.setUsuarioPadrao(0);
            em().merge(pessoa);
        }
        
     if (pes.getUsuarioPadrao().equals(0)) {
            pes.setUsuarioPadrao(1);
            em().merge(pes);
        }

    return pes;
}
```

nesse trecho eu mostro o modal se o valor for igual a 0

```
public static boolean exibirModalSelecionarUsuarioPadrao(DpPessoa usuario) {
    return (usuario.getUsuarioPadrao() != null && usuario.getUsuarioPadrao().equals(0));
}
```

e por último faço a verificação na jsp

```
<c:if test="${exibirModalSelecionarUsuarioPadrao}">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#modalEscolhaUsuarioPadrao').modal('show');
        });             
    </script>
</c:if>
```

obs: as matriculas no caso seriam funções diferentes que uma pessoa exerce, antigamente a pessoa logava no sistema com a matricula ao invés do cpf, e como haviam pessoas com quase 30 matriculas isso acabava ficando muito complicado, a intenção é logar pelo cpf tendo uma matricula padrão(uma que seja usada com maior frequencia). Com o código usado como exemplo eu consigo selecionar e setar a matricula padrão, na tela inicial tem um combo onde pode ser feita a troca das matriculas(essa troca não faz nenhuma alteração no banco, faz apenas um swap na matricula selecionada independente do valor que está no banco). Só que ao fazer essa troca pelo combo o modal é exibido novamente, pois a matricula selecionada tem o valor igual 0 (já que só pode ter uma matricula como padrão). O que estou querendo fazer é pegar essa lista de matriculas e verificar se todas estão zeradas, pro modal ser exibido apenas uma vez pro usuario escolher qual será definida como padrão, pois assim se eu selecionar uma matricula do combo apenas pra consulta e já tiver qualquer outra definida como padrão, o modal não será exibido mais.

Comment: Cara, de boa, eu não entendi quase nada da explicação, coisas como "logar na matrícula" e "objeto Pessoa com campo usuário padrão" não ficaram claras para mim. Votei para fechar como não-clara. Mas parece que no geral você precisa melhorar a modelagem dos seus objetos, o que é um assunto amplo e não dá para explicar tudo em uma resposta.

Comment: Matrícula que você está falando é o cadastro do usuário no sistema? Deduzi que é isso. Estava pensando em matrícula como algo específico de aulas/disciplinas/escolas. E cada pessoa tem uma lista de matrículas/cadastros que vem junto quando você traz o objeto pessoa do banco? Porque me parece que o usuário padrão deveria estar vinculado à matrícula e não à pessoa, aí você percorreria a lista de matrículas em busca de uma padrão. Ou cada pessoa é ao mesmo tempo uma matrícula? Está meio confuso. Se for, o que eu vejo é que não faz sentido você checar o usuário padrão de uma pessoa e sim da lista.

Comment: coloquei uma obs: explicando o que estou tentando fazer

Comment: Entendi. Você tem uma lista de objetos e quer saber só como faz pra saber se todos esses objetos são iguais. Não importa matrícula, usuário padrão, regra de negócio, nada. Reduza a pergunta a essa dúvida específica então senão vai ficar uma pergunta que só atende a você e não a outros usuários.

Comment: vou fazer isso obrigado

Comment: a verificação deve ser feita antes de ser gravado os dados. e não quando for resgatar dados. estude as classes List, Set e Map e Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma, percorri a lista e adicionei um contador, comparando o valor de cada matricula.

```
public static boolean exibirModalSelecionarUsuarioPadrao(DpPessoa pessoa) {
    
    List<DpPessoa> lista = CpDao.getInstance().listarPorCpf(pessoa.getCpfPessoa());
    int contador = 0;
    
    for (DpPessoa usuario : lista) {
        if(usuario.getUsuarioPadrao() == 0) {
            contador++;
        }
    }
    
    if(contador == lista.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se a interface `List` do Java tem um jeito de saber se todos os objetos são iguais, se tiver vai ter algum método na documentação da interface, mas acho que não tem. E de fato ela permite objetos iguais, seja pelo critério de unicidade da instância (ou seja, comparáveis com `==`) ou pelo de terem o mesmo conteúdo (ou seja, sobrescrevendo os métodos `equals()` e `hashCode()` que são sempre importantes sobrescrever quando você vai colocar objetos em coleções, e usando o `equals()` para comparar as instâncias em vez de `==`).

Primeiro você precisa saber que existem essas duas formas citadas de comparar e ver se é uma delas que você quer.

Aí você pode fazer de diversas formas, uma é percorrer a lista e ir verificando se o objeto `n` é igual ao `n-1` até que seja encontrado um diferente ou chegue ao fim da lista.

Outra forma é jogar esses itens em um `Set` (conjunto) e ver se tem mais de um elemento. Isso é para o caso de usar o `equals()`. No Set os elementos não se repetem, não podem ter dois iguais pelo critério do `equals()`, inserir um igual substitui o anterior.

Conclusão, se o Set ao final tiver tamanho 1, é porque só tinha um elemento igual na lista.

Uma forma simples de fazer:

```
Set conjunto = new HashSet(lista);
if (conjunto.size() == 1) { ...
```

Um pouco mais de informação:

[Quais as diferenças entre os métodos "equals()", "compareTo()", e até mesmo "=="?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427440/357)

[Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/357)

Comment: Eu sei que está como `Integer` (e não sei porque não um `int`) , mas não precisa haver essa relação 1 para 1 entre os tipos, pode muito bem ser um booleano no objeto que é mapeado para um inteiro no banco, fica mais fácil de tratar no código, em condições, etc. O tipo booleano não existe no Java à toa, no seu caso faz mais sentido querer saber se o usuário é padrão SIM ou NÃO e não um ou zero, mas como não deve existir o tipo booleano no banco, pode-se fazer o mapeamento (conversão).